# Retrieving a double relation

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following: retrieve all activities for the list of friends of a given user. Let me elaborate:

Given a User who has_many friends, through :friendships. A user has activities. Now what I would like to retrieve is a sorted list like so: user.friends.activities.order('created_at DESC'). Of course this doesn't work...

Do I really have to loop through all friends and compile an activities list, or is there a function this Rails-rookie (me) is missing :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
Activity.where(:user_id => user.friends).order('created_at DESC')
```